# Eclipse java class insert new line after method annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, ide, code-formatting

When using eclipse to create a class and set a master class (extends X) or an interface (implements Y) it formats automatically when creating the class like this:

```
public class class1 extends X {

    @Override
    public void setX(int x){
        //todo
    }
}
```

How do I make it so it would syntax like this?

```
public class class1 extends X {

    @Override public void setX(int x){
        //todo
    }
}
```

Where override is the same line as setX method?

Comment: @Ben That is not a duplicate, as that question is about IntelliJ IDEA, and this one is about Eclipse.

Comment: @Ben No, Android Studio is built on IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your formatting configuration for that:

1. Open `Window -> Preferences`
2. Select `Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`
3. Click `Edit` (You may need to rename your template before editing)

Uncheck the `Insert new line after annotation on methods` under the `Annotations` section:

[image]

Then just hit `Ctrl+Shift+F` to format the code.